# C++ thread_local with different threading library than std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

C++11 has keyword thread_local. I wanted to know whether this keyword works as expected only with threads created using standard library (std::thread) or it is guaranteed to work with other threading libraries e.g. Windows CreateThread function or Unix pthread.

[Microsoft documentation for visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thread) states that:

> The thread extended storage-class modifier is used to declare a thread local variable. For the portable equivalent in C++11 and later, use the thread_local storage class specifier for portable code. On Windows thread_local is implemented with __declspec(thread).

So thread_local works as expected in MS Visual Studio. I still wonder if the situation is true for other compilers and platforms.

Comment: Most likely implementation dependent.

Comment: This probably is UB. But does it actually work? Probably, as long as the library uses kernel threads. But you should not depend on any of that.

Comment: @freakish: I wouldn't assume that. The `std::thread` ctor might initialize threadlocal storage within kernel threads, for instance. It works on Windows because kernel thread have `TlsGetValue/TlsSetValue`.

Answer (score 7):

The C++ standard defines a thread as follows at [[intro.multithread]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.multithread#1):

> A *thread of execution* (also known as a *thread*) is a single flow of
>   control within a program, including the initial invocation of a
>   specific top-level function, and recursively including every function
>   invocation subsequently executed by the thread. [ Note: When one
>   thread creates another, the initial call to the top-level function of
>   the new thread is executed by the new thread, not by the creating
>   thread.  — end note ] Every thread in a program can potentially access
>   every object and function in a program. Under a hosted
>   implementation, a C++ program can have more than one thread running
>   concurrently. The execution of each thread proceeds as defined by the
>   remainder of this International Standard. The execution of the entire
>   program consists of an execution of all of its threads. [ Note:
>   Usually the execution can be viewed as an interleaving of all its
>   threads. However, some kinds of atomic operations, for example, allow
>   executions inconsistent with a simple interleaving, as described
>   below.  — end note ] Under a freestanding implementation, it is
>   implementation-defined whether a program can have more than one thread
>   of execution.

Note how the above is not at all limited to threads created by `std::thread`. Moreover, the standard even acknowledges the existence of **at least one** thread of execution that is not necessarily created by `std::thread`, over at [[intro.progress]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.progress#8):

> It is implementation-defined whether the **implementation-created thread
>   of execution** that executes main and the threads of execution created
>   by std​::​thread provide concurrent forward progress guarantees.
>   [ Note: General-purpose implementations are encouraged to provide
>   these guarantees.  — end note ]

Furthermore, while the following is a note, and cannot be considered normative, it's still encouraging to read [[thread.threads]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/thread.threads#1):

> [thread.threads] describes components that can be used to create and
>   manage threads. [ Note: **These threads are intended to map one-to-one
>   with operating system threads.**  — end note ]

Which to me all indicates that any `thread_local` storage can be used in any "thread of execution" that conforms to the above definition, regardless of whether it's created by `std::thread` or some implementation defined manner. I wouldn't expect a sane hosted implementation to behave otherwise.

Comment: it's a suggestion, not a concrete statement.

Comment: @DavidHaim - What? The note? I know, hence I called it non-normative. Everything else is normative however.

Comment: I mean to say that the standard may hint that it may work, but the standard doesn't really state so explicitly. your answer suggests that definitely, in my opinion.

Comment: @DavidHaim - My answer suggests that the standard defines a thread of execution without specifying how one must be created. And yes, the behavior of `thread_local` storage is well defined in a thread of execution, no matter how created. If the implementation offers more ways to create threads, that conform to the standard definition, then any `thread_local` storage in those threads will behave as the standard dictates.

Comment: Creating a native thread is almost certainly going to involve Undefined Behavior somewhere, at least in a formal sense. That's a theoretical cop-out. But the non-normative wording highlights the intent of "no gratuitous incompatibilities".

Comment: Whether the threads map to OS threads (what does that mean anyway, threads scheduled by the kernel? Or OS API threads?) is not important, but whether they map to the same thing. E.g., whether `thread_local` will work correctly with a thread created using Win32 API. Since the standard doesn't mention a relation with these platform-specific functions, these seem to be murky waters. The thing is, even if we agree that it will work with OS API threads, there are third party thread libraries as well. It seems impossible to guarantee that they are all "well-behaved" wrt `thread_local`.

Comment: I would be quite surprised if both thread_local construction on/before first use, and destruction on thread exit worked properly on all platforms and compilers.  Has anyone run experiments to confirm or deny this behavior?